# Google Apps Script error when trying to read into a database using jdbc

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, google-apps-script

I have a google apps script that is working in one instance, but not another

Both scripts are identical, the only difference I have programmed is the jdbc query.

Here is the working function:

```
function wbk() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://aaa.aaaa.org:3306/aaaaa", "aaaa", "bbbbb");
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.setMaxRows(10000);
  var start = new Date();
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT `DateUpdate`, `AllianceName`, `PlayerName`, `Score`, `Rank`, `TotalCities`, `FameTotal`, `FameRank`, `DefeatedTotal`, `DefeatedRank`, `PlunderTotal`, `PlunderRank` FROM `Member` WHERE AllianceID='2' OR AllianceID='48'");
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var first = doc.getSheetByName("WBK");
  first.activate();
  var cell = first.getRange('b2');
  var row = 0;
  while (rs.next()) {
    for (var col = 0; col < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); col++) {
      cell.offset(row, col).setValue(rs.getString(col + 1));
    }
    row++;
  }
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log("time took: " + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
};
```

I ran this twice, after updating the db and the results were perfect, just what was expected.

Now, when I try to use the same function, and only modify the query (and I checked the SQL statement in the db, that's just fine), the function fails.

Here is the non working function.

```
function WC_Combined() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://aaa.aaaa.org:3306/aaaaa", "aaaa", "bbbbb");
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.setMaxRows(10000);
  var start = new Date();
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT `DateUpdate`, `AllianceName`, `PlayerName`, `Score`, `Rank`, `TotalCities`, `FameTotal`, `FameRank`, `DefeatedTotal`, `DefeatedRank`, `PlunderTotal`, `PlunderRank` FROM `Member` where AllianceID='195' OR AllianceID='494'");
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var first = doc.getSheetByName("Combined");
  first.activate();
  var cell = first.getRange('b2');
  var row = 0;
  while (rs.next()) {
    for (var col = 0; col < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); col++) {
      cell.offset(row, col).setValue(rs.getString(col + 1));
    }
    row++;
  }
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log("time took: " + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
};
```

The error message I get in the debug console on Google is

```
Service error: Spreadsheets (line 110, file "Code")
```

Line 110 in my code is `cell.offset(row, col).setValue(rs.getString(col + 1));` in the second function I have provided above; I cannot find any difference between this line in the 2nd function or the 1st example I have provided ---- and they both worked the first time I tried to run them.

Any ideas, anyone? I haven't even used custom code, the code is basically the google apps documentation example.

I am using Google scripting within a Google Docs Spreadsheet, connecting to mysql. I've opened up the remote connections to mysql, and have 2 working spreadsheets, so I know the connection works.

Answer (score 0):

[Issue 703](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=703) in the Issue Tracker has continued to see users report instances of this since July 2011. Visit and star the issue for updates, and add any information that may help the googlers to isolate the issue.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. nice to know I don't suffer alone. I updated the tracker.  Funny thing is, I had to delete the sheet with the problems, and then add again. Was a bit of pain to recreate the named ranges, but everything worked like a charm after that, so it definitely wasn't the code.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your loops are putting too much strain on the Spreadsheet API?

I would be more enclined to filling up a data structure from my sql rows and then appliying the resulting two dimensional data array to the correct range.

```
var data = [];
while (rs.next()) {
    var rowData = [];
    for (var col = 0; col < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); col++) {
        rowData[col] = (rs.getString(col + 1));
    }
    data[row] = rowData;
    row++;
}

var range = first.getDataRange(1,2,row, col+1); // check edges or uses a1 notation

range.setValues(data);
```

This has the advantage of being much more efficient as well, and won't stress the API with a quick doubl e loop.

Let me know how it goes, if you need any more info.